# Django : NameError at /approved/filter/7/ - name 'testElement' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to Django and I am trying to send a different context variable depending on which if statement is satisfied. This is my view:

```
class FilterSearch(View):
    template_name = 'approved/approvedElementsSEView.html'

    def post(self,request,testPlanId):
        elemType = request.POST.get('testElementType');
        elemCategory = request.POST.get('category');

        if(elemCategory=='routing'):
            global testElement;
            testElement=ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, routing='y');
            return testElement
        elif(elemCategory=='switching'):
            global testElement;
            testElement = ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, switching='y');
            return testElement


        return render(request,self.template_name,{'testElement':testElement,'testPlanId':testPlanId})
```

I was initially getting an UnboundLocalError:local variable 'testElement' referenced before assignment , which I tried fixing by defining testElement as a global variable, Now I am getting a NameError: name 'testElement' is not defined. Any Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens if neither `if`/`elif` are true?  By the way, the `;` at the end of a line are not required, and neither are the parentheses around the conditions (although they are not affecting the error).

Comment: Global is not the right solution here; you shouldn't just use it randomly to solve name errors. And why are you returning both inside the if and elif, and at the end of the method?

Comment: Thank you! I made the above mentioned changes and removed elif and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

class FilterSearch(View):
    template_name = 'approved/approvedElementsSEView.html'

```
def post(self,request,testPlanId):
    elemType = request.POST.get('testElementType');
    elemCategory = request.POST.get('category');

    if(elemCategory=='routing'):
        testElement = ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, routing='y');
    if(elemCategory=='switching'):
        testElement = ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, switching='y');   


    return render(request,self.template_name,{'testElement':testElement,'testPlanId':testPlanId})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'l need to handle few more cases.

Case 1:- What if elemCategory is undefined?

Case 2:- What if elemCategory is not 'routing' or 'switching'?

Maybe this will help.

```
def post(self,request,testPlanId):
    elemType = request.POST.get('testElementType')
    elemCategory = request.POST.get('category')

    if elemCategory:
        if(elemCategory=='routing'):
            testElement = ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, routing='y')
        if(elemCategory=='switching'):
            testElement = ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, switching='y')
        if not (elemCategory=='routing' or elemCategory=='switching'):
            testElement = 'Not Found!' #You can change this to your requirement

    else:
        testElement = 'Not Found!' #You can change this to your requirement

    return render(request,self.template_name,{'testElement':testElement,'testPlanId':testPlanId})
```

Or

```
def post(self,request,testPlanId):
    elemType = request.POST.get('testElementType')
    elemCategory = request.POST.get('category')
    testElement = 'Not Found!' #You can change this to your requirement

    if elemCategory:
        if(elemCategory=='routing'):
            testElement = ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, routing='y')
        if(elemCategory=='switching'):
            testElement = ApprovedTestElement.objects.filter(testElementType=elemType, switching='y')

    return render(request,self.template_name,{'testElement':testElement,'testPlanId':testPlanId})
```

Comment: Thank you! Will do so :)